# How to clear MySQL query profiles

Tags: mysql, profiling, database-performance

After turning on profiling in MySQL

```
  SET profiling=1;
```

I can run like a query like `SELECT NOW();`  and see profile results with it's execution time using:

```
  SHOW PROFILES;
```

However, I can't figure how to clear out the profile listing.  Anyone know the statement to delete old profile data? `SET profiling=0;` just disables logging of new data and doesn't remove old stats.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To remove previous query profiles set `@@profiling_history_size=0`. The following snippet clears the profiles, sets the history to its maximum size and enables profiling

```
SET @@profiling = 0;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 0;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 100; 
SET @@profiling = 1;
```

Tested on 5.6.17

Comment: This does remove the previous queries, but doesn't reset the auto-increment id. I don't want to have to keep updating the query id in my debugging, but I don't have (or want) permission to issue an `ALTER TABLE PROFILING AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` - is there another way to reset it? thanks (and I tried setting profiling_history_size=1)

Comment: when in an MySQL editor, you can stop a query being executed. This seems to reset the profiling, and the auto_increment!

Answer (score 5):

For completeness' sake: Closing the current connection to the server and reconnecting resets the profiling counts.

Answer (score 3):

Profiling information is stored under `information_schema.profiling` temporary table as referenced in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/profiling-table.html

Under a database user that has the required access level you can truncate the information stored there, if the engine allows it;

`TRUNCATE TABLE information_schema.PROFILING;`

If not you can restart the MySQL server, as `information_schema` is stored solely in memory, profiling information is not preserved after service restart.

Comment: This makes sense. However, with a root account and set to what I thought was 100% permission for everything I get the following: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'`.  Do you know what would control this permission?

Comment: You can restart mysqld and the tables will be recreated. `information_schema` is stored solely in memory and consists of views, profiling information is not preserved after a service restart.

Comment: Yes, the restart worked, but is not the preferred method--especially on the live machine or one other developers are using.  Are the tables read-only tables in the info schema?

Answer (score 2):

I found with MySQL 8 this solution didn't work for me.

However a small tweak and it does.

```
SET @@profiling = 1;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 0;
SET @@profiling = 0;
SET @@profiling_history_size = 1000;
```

For ease I just create a stored procedure so I can easily just run

```
CALL clearProfilingHistory();
```

to create it just run

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `clearProfilingHistory`()
BEGIN
    SET @@profiling = 1;
    SET @@profiling_history_size = 0;
    SET @@profiling = 0;
    SET @@profiling_history_size = 1000; 
END;
```